# VideoToolbox examples on iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, video-toolbox

I see varied articles that point to iOS8 being able to do hardware encoding of h264.

I'm having trouble finding any real code examples of this, however, and I have trouble looking for a place to start.

Ideally, I want to be able to create h264 encoded segments that could be used in an HLS stream, for example.

Where do I start to use videotoolbox?

Comment: Have you seen https://www.objc.io/issues/23-video/videotoolbox/ ?

Comment: [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29778336/1375695) + the linked [videoCore](https://github.com/jgh-/VideoCore) project...

Comment: You might enjoy my implementation of seamless looping of HD video using video toolbox APIs: https://github.com/mdejong/H264SeamlessLooping

Answer (score 0):

I've uploaded the only working version of the Apple Developer Connection's sample project, VideoTimeline, to:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_exgT43OZJOMGFzb2hJcFVFU1k/view?usp=sharing

It is intended to be used in conjunction with the session #514 of the WWDC 2014. It is nearly identical to the original, but I removed the UIImagePickerController, and upgraded OpenGL rendering to 3.0 (from 2.0).

Although referenced throughout the web, the original cannot be downloaded anywhere else; however, I have a copy of it, too, if you want it.